# Replacing graph nodes with matrices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to label a graph with matrices. Suppose the graph is simple:

---

[image: GraphPlot]

---

And I have an array **mats** that contains the labels for vertices 1,2,3,4
(these are just random 0-1 matrices; ignore the entries):

---

[image: mats]

---

What is the appropriate syntax to employ `VertexRenderingFunction` to achieve having
each vertex `i` replaced by (an image of) the `MatrixForm` of `mats[[i]]`?
Or perhaps I am looking in the wrong direction entirely...?

I know this is elementary; thanks for your patience & advice!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using `DirectedEdge`s, which are designed to work with `Graph` as opposed to `GraphPlot`.  If you'd like to use `GraphPlot` and `VertexRenderingFunction`, you can do like so:

```
matrix[1] = {
   {0, 1, 0},
   {0, 0, 1},
   {0, 0, 1}
   };
matrix[2] = {
   {1, 0, 0},
   {1, 0, 1},
   {1, 0, 0}
   };
matrix[3] = {
   {1, 0, 1},
   {0, 0, 0},
   {0, 1, 1}
   };
matrix[4] = {
   {1, 1, 0},
   {0, 1, 1},
   {0, 0, 0}
   };
vertexRenderer[position_, v_] := 
  {Text[Framed[matrix[v], Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, 0.8],
     FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0.94, 0.85, 0.36]], position]};
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4},
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 VertexRenderingFunction -> vertexRenderer]
```

[image]

You might seriously consider using the newer (and generally better) `Graph` based functionality and leverage the fact that virtually anything can be a vertex - including your matrices.  Then, labeling the vertices is as simple as using `VertexLabels`.

```
Graph[{matrix[1] -> matrix[2], matrix[1] -> matrix[3], matrix[3] -> matrix[4]},
  VertexLabels -> "Name", PlotRangePadding -> {{0.01, 0.2}, {0.01, 0.2}}]
```

[image]

If desired, you can always use `VertexShapeFunction` to get more control over the appearance.

Comment: Thank you so much! The second method is especially easy.